# Can I use different .ideavimrc files for CLion and IntelliJ IDEA on the same machine?

Tags: intellij-idea, clion, jetbrains-ide, ideavim

So I am using both CLion and IntelliJ IDEA with IdeaVim Plugin and I have a configuration file `.ideavimrc` for IntelliJ IDEA.

I want to use a different configuration for CLion, yet the file name and path that IdeaVim looks for configuration is not editable.

Comment: Try if it works to reload the config via `:source </path/to/.ideavimrc>`. See also https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-690#comment=27-730600

Comment: Yes, this will work, as any path can be sourced. Not the ideal solution though. I could also have two files, one for CLion and one for IntelliJ IDEA and change the filename of the one I want to use to `.ideavimrc`. These are definitely workarounds but I would prefer something more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Currently it's not possible. Feel free to file a feature request at [the issue tracker of IdeaVim](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/VIM) and describe how do you expect it to work in more details.